# How do I set a string field to null in a Big Object using Apex?

Tags: string, null, big-object

Is that something that is not allowed?  Is it a bug?

I just tried and it did not seem to set anything.

The index of `Named_Entity_Big__b` is over the following, and I'd like to set `Result__c` to `null`:

1. Entity_Name_Hash__c
2. NLP_Data_Container__c
3. SectionIndex__c
4. Type__c

My code (Anonymous Apex) is below.

```
List<Named_Entity_Big__b> ents = new List<Named_Entity_Big__b>();

for (Named_Entity_Big__b ent : [SELECT Entity_Name__c, Context__c, Section__c,
                                         SectionIndex__c, Entity_Name_Hash__c,
                                         Result__c, Type__c, NLP_Data_Container__c,
                                         Automated_System__c, Automated_System_Version__c
                              FROM Named_Entity_Big__b]){

      ents.add(new Named_Entity_Big__b(
          Entity_Name_Hash__c = ent.Entity_Name_Hash__c,
          NLP_Data_Container__c = ent.NLP_Data_Container__c,
          SectionIndex__c = ent.SectionIndex__c,
          Type__c = ent.Type__c,
          Entity_Name__c = ent.Entity_Name__c,
          Section__c = ent.Section__c,
          Automated_System__c = ent.Automated_System__c,
          Automated_System_Version__c = ent.Automated_System_Version__c,
          Result__c = ''
      ));
}

List<Database.SaveResult> saveResults = Database.insertImmediate(ents);
for (Database.SaveResult res : saveResults) {
  System.assert(res.isSuccess());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `Result__c=null` instead of `Result__c=''`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson yep.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the behavior you are seeing is the result of the merging that occurs when [re-inserting of the Big Object records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_populate_apex.htm) where there is a matching index.

> Re-inserting a record with the same index but different data results in behavior similar to an upsert operation. If a record with the index exists, the insert overwrites the index values with the new data.

As there is no data in the Result__c field it is merging in the existing value. Here the empty string and null both appear to be considered no data.

As a workaround, consider [explicitly deleting the existing records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_delete.htm) and insert a new ones.

Comment: Ugh.  I am afraid you're right.  I wish there was a way to affirmatively set null.